# $\mathbb{C}$ as the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, linear-groups

It is known that $\mathbb{C}$ is a linear algebraic group as the set of matrices $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ with $a \in \mathbb{C}$. I read in some notes that $Lie(\mathbb{C})$, the Lie algebra associated to $\mathbb{C}$, is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$, but I cannot see why. I only know that if $G$ is a linear algebraic group, $Lie(G)$ is the set of all $\phi : O(G) \to O(G)$ (where $O(G)$ is the set of regular functions on $G$) that satisfy Leibniz rule and such that $g \cdot \phi(f) = \phi(g \cdot f), \forall g \in G, \forall f \in O(G)$. It looks hard to use this definition, so I was thinking of using the fact that $Lie(\mathbb{C})$ is isomorphic to the tangent space, but I am not really sure how. Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you want to see $\Bbb C$ as a linear group, you should see it isomophic to$$\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1&a\\0&1\end{bmatrix}\,\middle|\,a\in\Bbb C\right\};$$that set that you mentioned is not a group.

Clearly, this group is $1$-dimensional. Therefore, its Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ is a $1$-dimensional complex Lie algebra. And the only way of defining a Lie braket $[\cdot,\cdot]$ on a $1$-dimensional vector space $V$ is to define $[x,y]=0$ for every $x$ and every $y$ in $V$. So, yes, it is naural to see $\mathfrak g$ as $\Bbb C$ endowed with the trivial braket.

Comment: Why must the Lie algebra associated to a $1$-dimensional group be $1$-dimensional?

Comment: Because, as a vector space, it is (isomorphic to) the tangent space of that group at the identity element. And the tangent space of a $n$-dimensional thing at any of its points is a $n$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: @cip I know that Jose knows this, but the tangent space at an $n$-dimensional *smooth* group is $n$. In characteristic $0$ this is contentless since all groups (with finite type hypotheses) are smooth, but in characteristic $0$ this is false in general.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I think there is a typo in your answer, you wrote characteristic $0$ twice: what is the characteristic for which all groups are smooth?

Comment: @cip Characteristic 0. In characteristic $p>0$ it's false (e.g. $\mu_p$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$).

Answer (score 3):

[In your setting both the group $G$ and the underlying field $k$ "are" the complex numbers (once, its additive group viewed as algebraic group, once as field), which can be confusing. So in the following I will use the notations $k$ and $G$. If you insert "$\mathbb C$" for both, see what a mess this would become!]

If you want to use the language in your question, you can also proceed by showing:

- $O(G)$ is isomorphic to the polynomial ring $k[T]$ where further
- the element $a \in G$ acts on a polynomial $p(T)$ via $p(T) \mapsto p(T+a)$

Then an element of the Lie algebra as defined in your post is a $k$-linear map $\phi: k[T] \rightarrow k[T]$ such that $\phi(f\cdot g) = \phi(f) \cdot g + f \cdot \phi(g)$. Show that this condition entails that $\phi$ is completely determined by $\phi(T)$, and that $\phi(c)=0$ for all constants $c$. Then, the compatibility with the $G$-action says that, if $\phi(T) = \sum c_iT^i$, we have

$$ \phi(T+a)= \sum c_i (T+a)^i$$

for all $a \in G$, but by $\phi$ being linear and our already established $\phi(a)=0$, the left hand side is just $\phi(T) = \sum c_i T^i$. Show that this is impossible unless $c_i = 0$ for all $i \ge 1$. Consequently $\phi(T) = c_0$ is a constant, and you can now show that $\phi$ must have been the differential operator $c_0 \cdot \dfrac{d}{dT}$ all along.

So $Lie(G)$, as a $k$-vector space, is the set $\{c_0 \cdot \dfrac{d}{dT} : c_0 \in k\}$ which obviously is of $k$-dimension $1$. You can now either use the fact that in any $1$-dimensional Lie algebra every Lie bracket is $=0$, or use whatever definition of the Lie bracket is given in your source to see that it is identically $0$ here. Probably all you need for that is that $G$ is abelian.

Worthwhile: Look at the two alternative definitions of the Lie algebra of an algebraic group in chapter 12b of [Milne's online book draft](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/iAG200.pdf), and see how they identify with our result above. (Most directly you should be able to identify, in 12.5, our $\phi$ with  Milne's $D$ once you see that in our setting, $I/I^2 = T \cdot k[T]/ T^2 \cdot k[T]$.) Note also that then your example is a special case of both 12.6. and 12.7.